# Using Metachars in Lookbehind, (?<=test this zzzz .+L)

Tags: php, regex

The text is like this:

```
$string = "  <L UXUHSXUS>importantText</L>";
```

I would like to use the lookbehind feature in PHP Regular Expression
but it generates an error everytime I try to put .+ or any regular expression things

```
preg_match_all('%(?<=<L.+>)([\s\S]*?)(?=</LF>)%',$string, $matches);
```

this gives an error.

what should I do to add `.+` or `.*` or any reserved regular expression things in lookbehind and lookahead?

Comment: Are you trying to [parse HTML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/)? At the end of that path only madness awaits.

Comment: yeaa I know its not the ideal, its much better to use some good parser out there, but since its predictable what is coming (therefore its not from regular users) its alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only use positive lookarounds you could probably replace all lookarounds with non-capturing groups `(?:)` instead:

```
(?:<L.+>)([\s\S]*?)(?:</LF>)
```

Note that you might want to make the first search non-greedy:

```
(?:<L.+?>)([\s\S]*?)(?:</LF>)
```

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what I was looking for, but just for curiosity what is the difference of this one and positive/negative lookarounds? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. [Lookbehinds](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) don't support full regexes. The pattern(s) must have a fixed length, though if you're using alternate patterns (with `|`), each alternate doesn't have to have the same length as the others:

```
/(?<=foo|quux|foobar)duck/
```